# Wrong Region Detected in Browser

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome

I moved from Canada to USA but some webpages still detect my region as Canada.

This happens in all browsers, even after I clear their browser data.

I assume then the browser is sending some region data based on the computer setting.  I have switched my region to United States and my language and keyboard settings to English (US).  However, the problem still persists.

I am at a bit of a loss of what to try next.

Comment: It could be some cache that just won't stop believing... This wouldn't necessarily solve anything, but what if you make a new user and see if that has those same issues?

Comment: Made another user and the problem persists there too.  It was a good idea to check that, thanks.

Comment: Could I suggest you [update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/306527/edit) your question to include: (1) the version of macOS you're running, (2) the model of Mac you're using, and (3) a couple examples of websites that are detecting the wrong region?